# Question regarding the mass of an alpha particle when travelling at a speed approaching the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light

The speed of an Alpha particle is: 10^7 m/s.

This is a speed approaching the speed of light. hence, should the (relativitic) mass of the Alpha particle vary?

Comment: The relativistic mass increases by a factor of 1.006 compared to its rest mass. $\gamma=\frac{1}{sqrt(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})}$

Comment: No, this is wrong. See comment to answer below.

Comment: BTW, Aman, $10^7\,\mathrm{m/s}$ is about 3% of $c$, so it is mildly relativistic but I would not characterize it as "approaching the speed of light".

Answer (score -1):

According to the special relativity, there is a formula describing the relation of particle mass with its speed:
$$m = {m_0 \over \sqrt {1- ({v \over {c}})^2}}$$
where $m_0$ is the mass of the particle when it is still----rest mass.

***So as long as a particle moves, no matter how large or small the velocity is, the mass of the particle $m$ will vary and be different from its rest mass $m_0$.***

If $v$ is small, the change in mass is very small. In this case, the ignorance of the change in mass is a good approximation for describing the system you are concerned, that is, back to Newton's world---the mass of a particle is constant. On the other hand, if $v$ is so large that it can be comparable with the speed of light, the change in mass is remarkable. So in this case, we must take the variance of the particle mass into consideration!

Comment: No, this is wrong. Widely believed but nonetheless wrong. It's momentum and kinetic energy that vary relativistically when speed approaches $c$, not mass itself, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity.

Comment: yes, it is true. But I think it's just a matter of angle to consider this formula. I remembered that the way I used existed a long time ago. Now the common explanation is just what you said.

Comment: No, it's not a 'matter of angle'. You're contributing to the dissemination of a misconception. That should not stand on a forum about physics.

Comment: ......It is true that considering this problem in terms of momentum is favored right now. But it does not mean the way I described is absolutely wrong.

Comment: @Gert. To say "wrong" about relativistic mass is too dogmatic. It is possible to formulate relativity with that language (and indeed it was the usual language for decades), it's just that the language creates unnecessary confusion without adding anything essential so the modern approach does away with it and only talks about the invariant mass. I'm a strong proponent of the modern usage, but a combative approach is not a good way to bring people around.

Comment: @dmckee: combative? The choice is between allowing it to stand and contribute to the confusion or taking it down. As far as I can see, taking it down has been the policy for a number of questions and answers in the same vein. The poster had the chance to be subtle and chose not to. The poster should retract or edit strongly.

Comment: There is no 'policy' on this, there is the behavior of people, and if you are trying to educate people being strident and accusatory is counterproductive.

Comment: @dmckee: what is strident about claiming he's wrong? About suggesting he should edit?

Comment: I thank you all for you're valuable comments , i also apologize , Gert ,  for duplicating and  for causing confusion.